# compute difference between lists in dictionary values

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I have some dictionaries generated dynamically. They are generated using `from collections import defaultdict` and are as follows:

```
  a= defaultdict(list, {'speed_limit': [('0', '70')]})
  b= defaultdict(list, {'speed_limit': [('0', '70'),('0', '60'),
                                ('0','50')],'road_obstacles': [('0', '8')]})
```

**What I want**

- Print nothing if 'a' is in 'b' which is true in the above case. Only
  print when keys or values inside are different.
- In the above case, `a` has 1 tuple and `b` has 3 tuples, but `a`'s tuple 
  is a part of `b`'s one so there should not be any difference.

**What I tried**

I tried a very conservative approach of nested loops which works but is not efficient. Additionally, it fails to handle the case when structures i am comparing get complex.

This is what i tried and this approach is very inefficient for large structures:

```
for key,value in a.iteritems():
    for key1,value1 in b.iteritems():
        if key!=key1:
           print "doesn't matches", key,value, key1,value1
        if key==key1: #check for values
            if value==value1: #if values are same
               print "key and value matches", key,value,key1,value1
            if value!=value1: #if values not same 
               print "key matches but value differs", key,value,key1,value1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're iterating over both dictionaries, essentially generating a Cartesian product. Sounds to me like what you really want is a union.

The union operator is `|`. It works on sets. To find the union of all the keys in the two dictionaries, use <s>`set(a.keys()) | set(b.keys())`</s>

*Edit:* [ivan_pozdeev points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323026/compute-difference-between-lists-in-dictionary-values/31323620#comment50637726_31323620) that the sets can be calculated faster using `set(a) | set(b)`.

You can then just iterate over that set once, checking `key in a`, `key in b`, and whether the values have common elements (`set(a_value) & set(b_value)`) as necessary. Here's an example:

```
all_keys = set(a.keys()) | set(b.keys())
for k in all_keys:
    if k in a:
        if k in b:
            print("Key is in both dictionaries:",k)
            a_value,b_value = a[k],b[k]
            if set(a_value) & set(b_value)):
                print("Values match")
            else:
                print("Values do not match")
        else: print("Key is in a but not b:",k)
    else: print("Key is in b but not a:",k)
```

That's just one way of doing it. Another way would be to calculate three sets: `set(a.keys()) - set(b.keys())` for keys in `a` but not in `b`, `set(b.keys()) - set(a.keys())` for keys in `b` but not in `a`, and `set(a.keys()) & set(b.keys())` for the keys that are in both dictionaries.

Comment: A nitpick: `a.keys()` can be replaced with just `a`: a `dict` is an iterable over its keys. A more considerable difference is `.keys()` produces a full `list` which is slower for large sequences.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev thanks, that wouldn't have occurred to me! Great tip.

Comment: To back this with numbers, on my Pentium 3 933MHz, it's `105ms` vs `48.5ms` for a dict of ~80k items and `2.79 us` vs `1.15 us` with a large deviation for a dict of 2.

Answer (score 1):

For set operations, the fastest approach should be to convert the `dict`s to `set`s and use those from `set` implementation (as they are implemented in C):

```
>>> [
    set((k,iv) for k,v in var.iteritems() for iv in v)
    for var in a,b]
[{('speed_limit', ('0', '70'))},
 {('road_obstacles', ('0', '8'))
  ('speed_limit', ('0', '50')),
  ('speed_limit', ('0', '60')),
  ('speed_limit', ('0', '70'))}]
>>> sa,sb=_
>>> sb > sa
True
>>> sb - sa
{('road_obstacles', ('0', '8')),
 ('speed_limit', ('0', '50')),
 ('speed_limit', ('0', '60'))}
>>> sa - sb
set()
```

- Pros: all complex operations are in C
- Cons: an initial step with a loop, although optimization-friendly (maybe you're better off storing them as `set`s from the start? The decision depends on how often you need to perform `set`-friendly vs `dict`-friendly operations)
- A `timeit` test on the variables in your example shows the times are roughly the same:

  ```
  def loops(): <your code>
  def sets(): <my code up to b-a>
  <a and b are being taken from the interactive namespace>

  In [85]: timeit sets
  The slowest run took 14.36 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that a
  n intermediate result is being cached
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 253 ns per loop

  In [86]: timeit loops
  The slowest run took 13.23 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that a
  n intermediate result is being cached
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 253 ns per loop
  ```
- A `timeit` test on a randomized example with ~1000 elements shows that my code appears to start outperforming yours but the discrepancy is high:

  ```
  In [64]: alphabet='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_'
  In [41]: gen_word=lambda:''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for i in range(random.randrange(0,15)))
  In [66]: a={gen_word():[tuple(random.randrange(100) for _ in range(2)) for _ in range(random.randrange(10))] for _ in range(1000)}
  In [67]: b=a.copy()
  In [69]: b.update({gen_word():[tuple(random.randrange(100) for _ in range(2)) for _ in range(random.randrange(10))] for _ in range(500)})
  In [74]: a.update({gen_word():[tuple(random.randrange(100) for _ in range(2)) for _ in range(random.randrange(10))] for _ in range(200)})
  In [70]: len(b)
  Out[70]: 1336
  In [75]: len(a)
  Out[75]: 1067
  In [76]: timeit loops
  The slowest run took 9.94 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an
   intermediate result is being cached
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 337 ns per loop

  In [77]: timeit sets
  The slowest run took 14.43 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that a
  n intermediate result is being cached
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 252 ns per loop
  ```

Comment: This is very brief explanation. Its very helpful. well I will have to combine your's and sam's approach. It was hard to accept one answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll consider that a "second prize" :)

Comment: :) Also, I am glad you edited all errors in my post. I just saw my syntax and spell errors in revised post. I am not a native speaker but I will take care next time.